# MEANJS: Best way to send base64 image to server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, base64, meanjs

### Situation

I'm using [MEAN.JS](http://meanjs.org/) framework ([MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/), [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/), [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) and [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/)).

Using **AngularJS** in frontEnd; I have a **JSON** with a **base64** encoded **image** in a field.

### What I want?

- I want to send this JSON to the server (**NodeJS**).

I'm using **RESTful**:

***controller***:

```
var article = new Articles ($scope.article);


article.$save(function(response) {
    //If all is OK
}, function(errorResponse) {
    //Error 
 });
```

`$scope.article` have a field named "**image**" *($scope.article.image)* with the base64 string of the image.

***service:***

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('articles')
    .factory('articles', ['$resource',

    function($resource) {
        return $resource('articles/:articleId', { articleId: '@_id'
        }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });
    }
]);})();
```

### Problems

If the JSON don't have any Base64 Image in a field works fine...

But...

If we add the Base64 String of the Image in a field the server response with this **error**:

```
    Error: request entity too large at makeError (/Users/aralroca/Documents/Aral/Projecte/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:184:15)
at module.exports (/Users/aralroca/Documents/Aral/Projecte/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:40:15)
at read (/Users/aralroca/Documents/Aral/Projecte/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:62:3)
at jsonParser (/Users/aralroca/Documents/Aral/Projecte/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:96:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/aralroca/Documents/Aral/Projecte/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
at trim_prefix (/Users/aralroca/Documents/Aral/Projecte/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:269:13)
at /Users/aralroca/Documents/Aral/Projecte/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:236:9
at Function.proto.process_params (/Users/aralroca/Documents/Aral/Projecte/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:311:12)
at /Users/aralroca/Documents/Aral/Projecte/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:227:12
at Function.match_layer (/Users/aralroca/Documents/Aral/Projecte/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:294:3)
```

Say that the request entity **is too large**... The image size is **84Kb**!!!!!

*(I tried with [$http resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and occurs the same...)*

- How can I solve this server error?
- What is the best way to send from Angular to Node a Base64 encoded image?
- Any suggestions?

Relationed answers:

- [Error: request entity too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/node-js-express-request-entity-too-large)
- [MEANJS : 413 (Request Entity Too Large)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287968/meanjs-413-request-entity-too-large)

I tried to do this but don't work and don't understand:

```
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb'}));
 app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
```

bodyParser is deprecated and the size of the Base64 Image is **84kb!!!!!**

*Thank you!!*

Comment: Is the app behind a proxy? In that case check the proxy config too.

Comment: Try using this [private npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-image).

Comment: Im also sending a base64 image via post request and also had some trouble with the size. I have in my express config: `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));`  and `app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));` and it's working fine.

Comment: mmm don't work now this solution because bodyParser is now deprecated... Another way, I don't understand why happen this... For default the limit is in 1MB but the size of the base64 image is 84kb only... Maybe there are a code similiar to bodyParser.urlencoded and bodyParser.json not deprecated? Thank you!

Comment: @sam100rav I tried with base64-image npm module and occurs the same problem!! Error: request entity too large ...

Comment: @jmingov is in localhost using grunt, there aren't any proxy.

Comment: localhost using grunt > Looks like grunt development server is not getting the app use config.

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');

app.post("/url_path",
busboy({
    limits: {
        fileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024
    }
}),
function(req, res, next) {
    // check that the request's body was as expected
    if (!req.busboy) return next('route'); // or next(new Error('...'));

    // ...
});
```

// ...

For more info checkout [this private npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy).

Comment: I tried now this solution but doesn't work and the problem already exists... Error: request entity too large...