# Error: request entity too large (mean.io)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean.io

I am trying to parse a .srt file and saving the parsed object in a mongodb collection. When I'm uploading a big srt file, I am getting the entity too large error. I googled around and found an express config line to increase the size limit of a request but that didn't seem to do the trick. This is what I get when I submit the file for saving:

JS Console:

```
POST                                             (angular.js:10514)
http://localhost:3000/api/subtitles 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Here is the complete error:

```
Error: request entity too large
at readStream (/Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:179:15)
at getRawBody (/Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:97:12)
at read (/Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:68:3)
at jsonParser (/Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:121:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at /Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server/node_modules/express-validator/lib/express_validator.js:163:5
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at cookieParser (/Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server/node_modules/cookie-parser/index.js:34:14)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at /Users/egills/MEANPanda/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server/ExpressEngine.js:41:5
```

Here is the http header:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,is;q=0.6
Authorization:Bearer <long key>
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:178471
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:3000
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/subtitles/create
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287968/meanjs-413-request-entity-too-large) is the solution I was hoping that would fix it but it does not. The SRT file Im testing is 107kb and the express config is [here.](https://github.com/egilsster/MEANPanda/blob/master/config/express.js)
I am running the app using the default gulp task in a developer enviroment.
Do I need to add the size config somewhere else? I tried adding it in the app.js file inside the subtitles package folder but that didn't do it either.

Comment: Check this it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287968/meanjs-413-request-entity-too-large

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/node-js-express-request-entity-too-large